# Buildozer apk crashes

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Hi I just created an apk using buildozer, but it just keeps crashing.
I used kivy garden iconfonts as as well as label base modules so as to enable use external fonts and icon fonts.
I'm stating dis because I can't tell what the problem is.
I ran the buildozer android log cat command to see if I can get some info fe the logcat, but I can't find what's crashing my app.
The app works perfectly on kivy launcher though.

I really don't know where to start, please I need assistance.

Here is the logcat info

```
 I/GLConsumer( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c067f8,api:2) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c147b0 handle=0xb8c1d100 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000003 I/BufferQueue( 134): [StatusBar](this:0xb8c2ff50,id:6,api:1,p:735,c:134) [release] fps:1.32, dur:2276.91, max:1455.20, min:305.19 I/BufferQueue( 134): [NavigationBar](this:0xb8c333e0,id:7,api:2,p:735,c:134) [release] fps:2.13, dur:11737.46, max:11150.57, min:22.93 W/ResourceType( 6058): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 V/python ( 6058): metadata fullscreen is0 D/SurfaceView( 6058): checkGLSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 I/SDLSurface( 6058): Surface will NOT be transparent I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 D/dalvikvm( 6058): create interp thread : stack size=128KB D/dalvikvm( 6058): create new thread D/dalvikvm( 6058): new thread created D/dalvikvm( 6058): update thread list D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x5fad8000 D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: created from interp D/dalvikvm( 6058): start new thread D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: notify debugger D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11 (Thread-492): calling run() D/ActivityThread( 6058): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41cc35d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41cc2d98 {org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}} V/PhoneWindow( 6058): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ccefa8 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} I/SurfaceFlinger( 134): EventThread Client Pid (6058) created W/ResourceType( 6058): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl.so 0x41cc7c58 V/PhoneWindow( 6058): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{41cd6558 org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ccefa8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} D/ActivityThread( 6058): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{41cc35d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41cc2d98 {org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}} I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0 I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-82](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue I/GLConsumer( 134): [void android::RingBuffer<TYPE>::resize(uint32_t, bool) [with TYPE = android::sp<android::BackupBuffer>; uint32_t = unsigned int]] 0xb8c18c8c resize to 10 (force=true) I/GLConsumer( 134): [void android::RingBuffer<TYPE>::resize(uint32_t, bool) [with TYPE = android::sp<android::BackupBuffer>; uint32_t = unsigned int]] 0xb8c18c8c resize to 0 (force=false) I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-82](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:134) consumerConnect consumer=(134:/system/bin/surfaceflinger) controlledByApp=false I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-82](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setConsumerName: unnamed-134-82 I/GLConsumer( 134): [unnamed-134-82](this:0xb8c0c9f0,api:0) GLConsumer I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setConsumerName: org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setDefaultBufferSize: w=1, h=1 V/WindowManager( 657): Changing focus from null to Window{423626b0 u0 org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3474 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:191 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:235 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:126 I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setDefaultBufferSize: w=600, h=976 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl.so 0x41cc7c58 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_image.so 0x41cc7c58 I/WindowManager( 657): Gaining focus: Window{423626b0 u0 org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity} I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_image.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_image.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/AALService( 135): enableAALEvent:1, 0 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_ttf.so 0x41cc7c58 E/ ( 6058): appName=org.test.easybudget:python, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/ ( 6058): 0 E/ ( 6058): appName=org.test.easybudget:python, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/ ( 6058): 0 I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:0,p:6058,c:134) connect: api=1 producer=(6058:org.test.easybudget:python) producerControlledByApp=true I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:608 h:976 f:1) handle(0xb8bfec78) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c30bf0, handle=0xb8bfec78, w=600, h=976, s=608, fmt=1 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_ttf.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_ttf.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_mixer.so 0x41cc7c58 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_mixer.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_mixer.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x60091ef0) (w:608, h:976, f:1) D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libpython2.7.so 0x41cc7c58 D/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) cancelBuffer: slot=0 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3 I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) setBufferCount: count=4 I/GraphicBuffer( 134): free buffer (w:608 h:976 f:1) handle(0xb8bfec78) I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffff D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): close handle(0x60091ef0) (w:608 h:976 f:1) I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:976 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8c14d60) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c07d68, handle=0xb8c14d60, w=976, h=600, s=976, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x600d2d20) (w:976, h:600, f:1) D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libpython2.7.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libpython2.7.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): Enabling debug mode 0 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libapplication.so 0x41cc7c58 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x60246c28) (w:768, h:768, f:1) D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libapplication.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libapplication.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_main.so 0x41cc7c58 I/GLConsumer( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c180b0,api:0) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c157e8 handle=0xb8c1bb10 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 V/WallpaperService( 735): Visibility change in com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine@41ff2ad0: 0 V/WallpaperService( 735): onVisibilityChanged(false): com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper$DrawableEngine@41ff2ad0 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_main.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsdl_main.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x41cc7c58 I/BufferQueue( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c2b9f0,id:78,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) consumerDisconnect I/BufferQueue( 134): [com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher](this:0xb8c2b9f0,id:78,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueue I/GraphicBuffer( 134): free buffer (w:1024 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8c1bb10) D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsqlite3.so 0x41cc7c58 D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): setViewport 600x976 <0x60245490> I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- setFrame I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true I/SurfaceView( 6058): Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true I/SurfaceView( 6058): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x41ccded0 I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-83](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue I/GLConsumer( 134): [void android::RingBuffer<TYPE>::resize(uint32_t, bool) [with TYPE = android::sp<android::BackupBuffer>; uint32_t = unsigned int]] 0xb8c07c1c resize to 10 (force=true) I/GLConsumer( 134): [void android::RingBuffer<TYPE>::resize(uint32_t, bool) [with TYPE = android::sp<android::BackupBuffer>; uint32_t = unsigned int]] 0xb8c07c1c resize to 0 (force=false) I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-83](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:-1,c:134) consumerConnect consumer=(134:/system/bin/surfaceflinger) controlledByApp=false I/BufferQueue( 134): [unnamed-134-83](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setConsumerName: unnamed-134-83 I/GLConsumer( 134): [unnamed-134-83](this:0xb8c2a758,api:0) GLConsumer I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setConsumerName: SurfaceView I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:-1,c:134) setDefaultBufferSize: w=600, h=951 V/SurfaceView( 6058): org.renpy.android.SDLSurfaceView{41ccda70 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-600,951} got resized: w=600 h=951, cur w=-1 h=-1 I/SurfaceView( 6058): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x41ccdfa0, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 25 - 600, 976) I/SurfaceView( 6058): Callback --> surfaceCreated I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceCreated callback + I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceCreated callback - I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=600 h=951 I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceChanged callback + D/dalvikvm( 6058): create interp thread : stack size=128KB D/dalvikvm( 6058): create new thread D/dalvikvm( 6058): new thread created D/dalvikvm( 6058): update thread list D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x60ae1000 D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=12: created from interp D/dalvikvm( 6058): start new thread I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceChanged callback - I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceRedrawNeeded I/SurfaceView( 6058): finishedDrawing D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=12: notify debugger D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=12 (Thread-493): calling run() I/SDLSurface( 6058): Choose egl configuration I/SDLSurface( 6058): Try to use graphics config R8G8B8A8S8 V/SurfaceView( 6058): Layout: x=0 y=25 w=600 h=951, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 951) D/dalvikvm( 6058): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsqlite3.so 0x41cc7c58 D/dalvikvm( 6058): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/org.test.easybudget-1/lib/libsqlite3.so 0x41cc7c58, skipping init D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x41cc7c58 E/dalvikvm( 6058): dlopen("/data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found D/dalvikvm( 6058): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so 0x41cc7c58 I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true I/SurfaceView( 6058): Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=true mReportDrawNeeded=true redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=true I/SurfaceView( 6058): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x41ccded0 E/dalvikvm( 6058): dlopen("/data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/org.test.easybudget/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found I/python ( 6058): Starting audio thread I/SurfaceView( 6058): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x41ccdfa0, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 25 - 600, 976) I/SurfaceView( 6058): surfaceRedrawNeeded I/SurfaceView( 6058): finishedDrawing V/SurfaceView( 6058): Layout: x=0 y=25 w=600 h=951, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 951) D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: exiting D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: bye! D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 600.00, 976.00) opaque 1 <0x60245490> E/ ( 6058): appName=org.test.easybudget:python, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/ ( 6058): 0 E/ ( 6058): appName=org.test.easybudget:python, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/ ( 6058): 0 W/SDLSurface( 6058): Create egl surface I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:0,p:6058,c:134) connect: api=1 producer=(6058:org.test.easybudget:python) producerControlledByApp=true I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:608 h:951 f:1) handle(0xb8c16698) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c0d628, handle=0xb8c16698, w=600, h=951, s=608, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x5faedb00) (w:608, h:951, f:1) D/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) cancelBuffer: slot=0 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1 I/MaliEGL ( 6058): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3 I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) setBufferCount: count=4 I/GraphicBuffer( 134): free buffer (w:608 h:951 f:1) handle(0xb8c16698) I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffff D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): close handle(0x5faedb00) (w:608 h:951 f:1) I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:960 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8c16698) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c0d628, handle=0xb8c16698, w=951, h=600, s=960, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x5faeee50) (w:960, h:600, f:1) D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): finish <0x60245490> I/GLConsumer( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c0c9f0,api:1) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c07d68 handle=0xb8c14d60 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000005 V/InputMethodManager( 6058): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=291 first=true flags=#1810100 V/InputMethodManager( 6058): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ccefa8 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-600,976} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41dd6560 controlFlags=#104 V/InputMethodManagerService( 657): windowGainedFocus: android.os.BinderProxy@4249faf0 controlFlags=#104 softInputMode=#123 windowFlags=#1810100 I/ActivityManager( 657): [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity: +859ms D/ActivityManager( 657): AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity:859:1235512 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 735): isInputRestricted: showing=false, needReshow=false, provisioned=true I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG I/ANRManager( 657): updateProcessStats I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- setFrame D/dalvikvm( 6058): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x612e3000 D/dalvikvm( 6058): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K (1949), 5% free 3895K/4088K, paused 3ms+11ms, total 57ms I/SurfaceView( 6058): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true I/BufferQueue( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c07558,id:82,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL D/dalvikvm( 6058): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:976 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8c36018) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c19bf0, handle=0xb8c36018, w=976, h=600, s=976, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x5bdbab28) (w:976, h:600, f:1) D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 600.00, 976.00) opaque 1 <0x60245490> D/OpenGLRenderer( 6058): finish <0x60245490> V/InputMethodManager( 6058): START INPUT: org.renpy.android.SDLSurfaceView{41ccda70 VFE..... .F...... 0,0-600,951} ic=org.renpy.android.SDLSurfaceView$3@41dd6c18 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41cc7ff8 controlFlags=#100 W/InputMethodManager( 6058): Ignoring onBind: cur seq=51, given seq=50 I/GLConsumer( 134): [org.test.easybudget/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity](this:0xb8c0c9f0,api:1) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c19bf0 handle=0xb8c36018 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x10000007 D/PowerManagerService( 657): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=1104409344 [ActivityManager-Launch], flags=0x0, total_time=962ms D/PowerManagerNotifier( 657): onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="ActivityManager-Launch", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=657, workSource=null D/PowerManagerService( 657): updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x0 D/PowerManagerService( 657): newScreenState = 2 D/PowerManagerService( 657): updateScreenStateLocked: mScreenBrightnessModeSetting=2, autoBrightness=false, ecoBrightness=true, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, screenBrightness=255 D/PowerManagerDisplayController( 657): requestPowerState: screenState=2, useProximitySensor=false, forceProximitySensorEnable=false, forceWakeUpEnable=false, screenBrightness=255, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, useAutoBrightness=false, useEcoBrightness=true, blockScreenOn=false, waitForNegativeProximity=false I/PowerManagerService( 657): setBrightness mButtonLight 0. D/PowerManagerService( 657): updateScreenStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, newScreenState=2, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x0, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true D/PowerManagerService( 657): Releasing suspend blocker "PowerManagerService.WakeLocks". V/ActivityManager( 657): ensureActivitiesVisibleLocked: consider front D/PowerManagerService( 657): handleSandman: canDream=true, mWakefulness=Awake V/ActivityManager( 657): ensureActivitiesVisibleLocked: consider back I/python ( 6058): presplash-fit is null I/python ( 6058): presplash (fit=null) mx=0.625000,my=0.990625 I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed I/GLConsumer( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c2a758,api:1) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c0d628 handle=0xb8c16698 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x1000000b I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:960 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8c15ab8) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c2fd40, handle=0xb8c15ab8, w=951, h=600, s=960, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x5fad9328) (w:960, h:600, f:1) I/BufferQueue( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c0cfb8,id:83,api:1,p:6058,c:134) new GraphicBuffer needed D/BufferQueue( 134): [OLD] gb:NULL I/GraphicBuffer( 134): allocate buffer (w:960 h:600 f:1) handle(0xb8bf9f88) err(0) I/BufferQueue( 134): [NEW] gb=0xb8c2bf98, handle=0xb8bf9f88, w=951, h=600, s=960, fmt=1 D/GraphicBuffer( 6058): create handle(0x5fad9a60) (w:960, h:600, f:1) I/libSDL ( 6058): Physical screen resolution is 600x951 I/python ( 6058): Initialize Python for Android I/GLConsumer( 134): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8c2a758,api:1) [void* android::GLConsumer::createImage(EGLDisplay, const android::sp<android::GraphicBuffer>&, const android::Rect&)] D/GLConsumer( 134): GraphicBuffer: gb=0xb8c2fd40 handle=0xb8c15ab8 fmt=1 D/GLConsumer( 134): EGLImage: dpy=0x1, img=0x1000000c I/BufferQueue( 134): [FrameBufferSurface_0](this:0xb8bf61d0,id:0,api:1,p:134,c:134) [release] fps:23.79, dur:1008.87, max:446.26, min:19.68 I/BufferQueue( 134): [FrameBufferSurface_0](this:0xb8bf61d0,id:0,api:1,p:134,c:134) [queue] fps:23.79, dur:1008.85, max:446.17, min:19.68 I/SurfaceFlinger( 134): [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:23.790016,dur:1008.83,max:446.11,min:19.68 D/GraphicBuffer( 657): close handle(0x644a4da0) (w:608 h:976 f:1) I/BufferQueue( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c34018,id:81,api:2,p:-1,c:134) disconnect: api=2 I/BufferQueue( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c34018,id:81,api:0,p:-1,c:134) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffff I/GLConsumer( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c067f8,api:0) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x10000002 I/GraphicBuffer( 134): free buffer (w:608 h:976 f:1) handle(0xb8c20498) I/GLConsumer( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c067f8,api:0) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x10000003 D/IPCThreadState( 134): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0xb8c07f28 D/GraphicBuffer( 657): close handle(0x64a59078) (w:608 h:976 f:1) I/BufferQueue( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c34018,id:81,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) consumerDisconnect I/BufferQueue( 134): [Starting org.test.easybudget](this:0xb8c34018,id:81,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueue I/GraphicBuffer( 134): free buffer (w:608 h:976 f:1) handle(0xb8c1d100) W/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): create_local_service_socket() name=shell:export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="" ; exec logcat W/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): service_to_fd() name=shell:export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="" ; exec logcat W/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): read_meminfo() mem_free=65596 W/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): create_subprocess() ret_fd=28 pid=6086 W/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): LS(2): bound to 'shell:export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="" ; exec logcat' via 28 D/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): adb local_socket_ready list (17) (28) W/ADB_SERVICES( 6086): adb: unable to open /proc/6086/oom_adj D/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): adb socket read list (17) (28) D/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): read_data=5125 D/ADB_SERVICES( 5870): max_read_time=0.000072 max_send_time=0.000068 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): PhoneStateListener:onDataActivity, sim0 before. V/Provider/Settings( 941): from settings cache , name = pdp_watchdog_poll_interval_ms , value = null D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): PhoneStateListener:onDataActivity, direction=0 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): updateDataIcon(0), SimState=UNKNOWN, DataState=2, DataActivity=0, tempNetworkType=Type_3G D/PhoneInterfaceManagerEx( 941): [PhoneIntfMgrEx] getCallState simId: 0 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): updateDataIcon(0), callState(0) is 0 D/PhoneInterfaceManagerEx( 941): [PhoneIntfMgrEx] getCallState simId: 1 D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): updateDataIcon(0), callState(1) is 0 D/SIMHelper( 735): isSimInserted(0), SimInserted=true D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 735): updateDataIcon(0), simColorId=
```

Comment: Post the full logcat output between starting your app and it crashing.

Comment: Sorry I took so long, had issues with adb. I'm hoping the log info isnt too bulky. My app's name is easy budget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally fixed it.
In my buildozer.spec file I added json, css, ttf to the source.include_exts, and after I created the apk it worked fine

Comment: Have you tried this in new buildozer tool chain.Namely buildozer android_new debug

Comment: No I haven't. Sure to look it up